# Changing panel using CardLayout from another class file?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jframe, jpanel

I'm having trouble using CardLayout, sadly. I'm wanting to use separate classes for each individual 'card' and then use buttons from within the card to change which card is being shown.

I think I know what's wrong, although not why, currently I'm calling the createAndShowGUI() method from the other classes so I can get at the switch statement but this seems to refresh all the code before the switch. I don't know why that's a problem but cardLayout.next(contentpane) works absolutely fine within the switch statement on the first run through but dies on me when I call it from an ActionListener in another class:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Bond extends JFrame{
    public static String Panel = "PROFILE";
    public static int PaneNo = 1;
    static int i = 0;
    static Profile callProfile = new Profile();
    static Profileset callProfileset = new Profileset();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        if(0 == i++){       
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FaceTweet+");
            frame.add(contentPane);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(686,242);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        Profile JPprofile = new Profile();
        Profileset JPprofileset = new Profileset();
        contentPane.add(JPprofile, "JPprofile");
        contentPane.add(JPprofileset, "JPprofileset");
        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();

        switch(Panel){
            case "HOMEPAGE": break;
            case "PROFILE":
                cardLayout.first(contentPane);
                PaneNo = 1;
                while(PaneNo != 1){
                    cardLayout.next(contentPane);
                    System.out.println("1");
                    PaneNo++;}
                break;
            case "PROFILESET":
                cardLayout.first(contentPane);
                PaneNo = 1;
                while(PaneNo != 2){
                    cardLayout.next(contentPane);
                    System.out.println("2");
                    PaneNo++;}
                break;
            default:
                cardLayout.show(contentPane, "JPprofile");
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void exit(int status){
        System.exit(status);
    }
}
```

The System.out.println() just tells me if the code is passing through the switch statement and then through the correct case, and it does every time however it never executes cardLayout.next(contentpane) after a button press from either class Profile of Profileset.
I hope that's enough info, if you need any more just say and I'll try and update this with the requested stuff! Thanks!